# Why dataframe is not displayed in console using pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**This is the session object I have created for dataframe**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

**This is the code for Dataframe creation**

```
data = [("James","","Smith",30,"M",60000),
        ("Michael","Rose","",50,"M",70000),
        ("Robert","","Williams",42,"",400000),
        ("Maria","Anne","Jones",38,"F",500000),
        ("Jen","Mary","Brown",45,"F",0)]

columns = ["first_name","middle_name","last_name","Age","gender","salary"]
pysparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
pysparkDF.printSchema()
pysparkDF.show(truncate=False)
```

**I want dataframe should be displayed in console of six columns but it is showing me the erro of Py4jjjavaerror exceeds size limit**

```
    Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 10
      8 pysparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
      9 pysparkDF.printSchema()
---> 10 pysparkDF.show(truncate=False)

File c:\Users\baps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:615, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    610 except ValueError:
    611     raise TypeError(
    612         "Parameter 'truncate={}' should be either bool or int.".format(truncate)
    613     )
--> 615 print(self._jdf.showString(n, int_truncate, vertical))

File c:\Users\baps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()
...
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:453)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Can you please post the Java error stack trace as well? Seems like something went wrong in the JVM, so posting that will definitly help us determining what's going wrong!

Comment: I have reposted whole error please check it

Comment: Hmmm that stack trace is missing a bunch of lines (where you wrote `...`). I'm also seeing `Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor` at the top. Maybe you should open this log in a file editor to be able to show the interesting part of the stack trace